# Proper data sanitation in java (jsp) before writing to a database?

Tags: java, security, jsp

I've been tinkering around with a personal project that involves me writing some variables to a mysql database, a few of these (first name, last name, email) are submitted, and I'm in the process of writing my own sanitation string.   I was thinking of doing something like

```
string allowed="@_=-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
string userEntered = [form submitted] // just skipping all the backstory there
for(int i=0; i<userEntered.length; i++){
    if(allowed.contains(userEnetered[i]){
       //continue processing
    }
    else{
        //flush data and deny
    }
}
```

Would something like that be sufficient?   Or are there other considerations that I'm forgetting about?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look up "placeholders". Do *not* create your own "sanitization" functions. (Business rules are a different matter; those should be defined/applied.)

Comment: In any case, regular expression are a much more concise way to describe/address this rule: but the rule above will *make some people unhappy* as their names will not conform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to write something to database in JSP, for sure, you should not use this type of SQL queries:

```
String sql = "Select * from tblUsers where Username = '" + usern + " and password = '" + pwd + "'";
```

If you use above method, you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Instead try to use prepared statements, they'll escape single quote charachters and make it impossible to do SQL injection attacks, like this:

```
String securesql = "Select * from tblUsers where Username = ? and Password = ?";
PreparedStatement prepstat = conn.prepareStatement(securesql);
prepstat.setString(1, usern);
prepstat.setString(2, pwd);
```

Also I suggest you to try using stored procedures and functions in SQL. For example for logging in create a stored procedure which will do queries and call it with parameters you have.

Also even you can do your string manipulation (like your example code) before passing to preparedStatement.

Comment: I always use prepared statements, and my actual idea was to make a data view to test the data on before pushing it to my live data as an extra step in testing for malicious intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about cross-site scripting attacks, the simplest first step is to HTML escape user-entered data when re-displaying it on a page rather than scrubbing it before saving it to the database.  You can use the JSTL escapeXml EL function to do this.  You just need to drop jstl.jar in WEB-INF/lib and then do something like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<input name="firstName" value="${fn:escapeXml(user.firstName)}">
```

This is a good start. If you're displaying user entered data in other contexts, like inside Javascript you need to escape it appropriately based on the context.  Check out the [OWASP cross-site scripting cheat sheet for good examples](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

If you are running into a situation where escaping user entered data before display is not sufficient, the [OWASP input validation cheat sheet is a good resource](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet) with examples of using whitelist input validation.